# How can I delete exe file written in c# after the task has completed?

Tags: c#-4.0, icons, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, auto

here I want to delete the file after the task or execution has completed. The exe is written in c#.

Is there anyway to auto-delete or self-destruct mechanism?

I tried google searching, but no avail. It will be helpful if someone can help me with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say add a file delete statement to the end of your code.

https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-delete-a-file-in-c-sharp

I hope this answers your question